# Lua passing multi dimensional array

Tags: function, multidimensional-array, lua, parameter-passing

Hi I am a fairly new Lua programmer and I am trying to pass parameters to a multidimensional  array, but I keep getting a nil value error.

I have a multidimensional array:

```
local transform = {
  forward = {
    distance = 1,
    swing = robot.swing,
    move = robot.forward
  },
  left = {
    distance = 1,
    swing = robot.swing,
    move = robot.forward
  },
  down = {
    distance = 1,
    swing = robot.swingDown,
    move = robot.down
  }
}
```

and I am trying to pass parts of the array like so:

```
function testFunc(transform, direction)
  print(transform.direction.distance)
end

myFunc(transform, forward)
```

Comment: Those are tables, not arrays. OK, in Lua arrays are tables, but they're not array-like tables. They're just key-value tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `transform.direction` looks up the value in `transform` whose key is the word "direction". If you want the value whose key is the value of the `direction` variable, use `transform[direction]` instead:

```
function testFunc(transform, direction)
  print(transform[direction].distance)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That answered my question